# Powershell is cutting off long output when connected to a terminal via SSH

Tags: powershell, ssh, posh-ssh

To put some context, I use the Posh SSH module to connect to linux machines on other servers and invoke command to get information of the current health of the machine.

When I use the command :

`Invoke-SSHCommand -Index 0 -Command "vm_manage.sh status"`

I got a truncated output of the command : [image: output]

This is normally the correct output for the command :

[image: outputok]

How can I make sure that I have the full output in powershell ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: idk the ```Invoke-SSHCommand ``` cmdlet, but what happens if you do: ```$result = Invoke-SSHCommand -Index 0 -Command "vm_manage.sh status" ``` and then ```$result | ft *``` ?

Comment: @Toni thanks for your answer ! but the result is the same (adding duration of the cmdlet)

Comment: I see, seems the output is stored in a attribute, does ```$result.output | ft *``` give you more

Comment: It's working ! I got the correct output with `$result.output | ft *`. I also found that adding the parameter `-ShowStandartOutputStream` is working too. Anyway thanks a lot @Toni

Answer (score 0):

Adding parameter `-ShowStandartOutputStream` is enough to have the correct output

`Invoke-SSHCommand -Index 0 -Command "vm_manage.sh status" -ShowStandartOutputStream`